# No Rows To Show

Tags: ag-grid

I have this columnDefs
[image]

To show a grid with months of years. And I have this rowData
[image]

That is. I have all the fields required in ColumnDefs but I only see in the grid the message "No Row to Show".

```
 <ag-grid-aurelia
 #agGrid
 style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
 class="ag-theme-balham"
 grid-options.bind="gridOptions"
 column-defs.bind="columnDefs"
 row-data.bind="rowData"
 >
 </ag-grid-aurelia>. 

private rowData:OutSourcingData[]=[];
```

Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: Maybe the grid is being rendered before the rowData is set (maybe a delay in the api response). Could you try adding a If condition in the template with boolean. That is set to false initially and to true after the rowData values being set.

Comment: If I use this.gridoptions.api.setRowdata(this.rowData); works fine but I have row-data.bind="rowData" to avoid to ue the api no?

Comment: `setRowData()` is used to remove existing rows and add new rows to grid. It is for cases when the row data needs to be updated after the initial loading and is not meant as a replacement for `row-data.bind="rowData"`

Comment: Could you try wrapping rowData setting inside a setTimeout like so. `window.setTimeout(() => this.rowData = data); ` Does that update the grid without calling setRowData()